# Visual studio 2019 debugging option IISExpress is gone from drop down

Tags: docker, debugging, iis-express

The options to debug with `IISExpress` in Visual Studio 2019 is not showing up in the debugger drop-down, it only shows the Docker compose option.

How can I get the `IISExpress` option to appear?

Here is my`launchsettings.json` file:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:56466",
      "sslPort": 44311
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "DirectoryTools": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/api/values",
      "httpPort": 10003,
      "useSSL": true,
      "sslPort": 44382
    }
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Shorten the question for clarity and add syntax language highlight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
You can enable IIS Express debug/run by selecting `Properties` from the solution (.sln) context menu, then in the `Startup project` menu, choose `Single startup project` radio button, and from the drop-down list select the `Project` that corresponds to your web application. After applying the change, in the toolbar you should see the "IIS Express" button re-appear.