# How to bring back IIS Express for Debugging in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I recently had to unload a project and reload it to fix a bug but now I dont have the option to start my code via IIS express anymore - instead it just says "Any CPU".
[image]

It used to say IIS Express (Google Chrome) and I can launch my web app through that but now it is gone and even going through the Web settings for debugging didn't fix it:
[image]

How can I bring back IIS Express so I can run my code properly again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I research the issue and found a couple of ways to bring the IIS Express option back.

You could try the approaches below one by one.

**Approach-1**

In Visual studio 2019, select the **solution**(.sln)-> **Properties**. Select the drop-down **Single Start-up project**. select your **project** from the dropdown. Click **OK**.

It should bring back the IIS Express option.

**Approach-2**

In Visual studio 2019, Go to **Tools**-> **Customize**-> **Commands** tab, then click on the **toolbar** radio button and choose the **standard** option from the drop-down and delete one of the existing toolbar inside the standard toolbar and then choose the option **reset all**.

[image]

Helpful references:

1. [Can't debug asp.net core api in visual studio 2019 (No button IIS Express)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/480091/can39t-debug-aspnet-core-api-in-visual-studio-2019.html)
2. [Visual studio 2019 debugging option IISExpress is gone from drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66022761/10309381)
3. [IIS Express hidden issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/iis-express-hidden-issue/972390)

Comment: Your first approach fixed it! Visual studio was actually making it start an automated WebJob program automatically, but I switched it to the current project and that brought back IIS Express. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to exit, and then re-load VS.
If not, then I would repair it.

I would also consider (yes, I know!!!) a reboot of your computer to flush out any running copy of IIS express.

The setting (choice) of what browser should be to the right in your menu like this:
[image]

So, clicking on that down arrow (chevron) in your start button should drop a list of options to choose which browser.